# Image button style issues in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have a XAML code as follows:

```
<Button 
    x:Name="stopButton" 
    Click="Stop_Click" 
    IsEnabled="False" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
    Height="75" 
    Width="75" 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    Margin="0,15,60,0" 
    BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
    Visibility="Collapsed" >
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/stop.png"/>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

With stop.png being the [following image](http://www.reignofcomputer.com/tmpsend/stop.png)

The button is enabled during an event in the app, and is pressed to stop media playback. When the button is pressed, it turns white as shown in the following image: [image: Comparison between normal, hover and pressed states]

I understand this is due to some Button Style issue, and was wondering how I would go about making this work better for me as a button.

Answer (score 1):

if this button is in AppBar Use predefined style for Stop button :

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource StopAppBarButtonStyle}" />
```

You just have to uncomment it in Common/StandardStyles.xaml (that file is included in project)

If button is not in AppBar you can set Segoe UI Symbol font and code for stop character :

```
<Button FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Content="&#xE1B5;"/>
```

You can see symbols here :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mohamedg/archive/2012/10/12/useful-segoe-ui-symbols.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The button is not part of the AppBar, so I can't use the AppBar Styles.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, completely slipped my mind - The stop button I used is an example, because I have several other images like it that are not part of the symbol set provided so I have to do it like how I originally posted. Also because the stop button I was looking for needed the circle around it, "Metro" style and that wasn't available in the symbol set.

Comment: you can use AppBarButton outside of the app bar.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create custom style for your button. Set all the visual states as you want.

[Button styles and templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709909.aspx#Default_style)

Answer (score 0):

use visual states to change button style

```
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="btnEffect">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                 <Storyboard>

                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGlyph">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="&#xE19A;" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="btnEffect">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">

              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>

          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>


          <StackPanel Name="btnEffect" Opacity="1"  Width="100" Height="100" Background="Gray" Canvas.ZIndex="100" >
              <TextBlock x:Name="BackgroundGlyph" Text="&#xE0A8;" 
                         FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" FontSize="53.333" Margin="-4,-19,0,0" 
                         Foreground="White"
                         Canvas.ZIndex="150"
            />

          </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```